# How can I get answers thru chat?

Tags: support, discussion

A while ago I asked https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7911/how-to-ask-this-question-about-star-wars-fan-theories on **SF&F *meta*** because I figured it'd be a little too broad and slightly opinion-based. So then I thought, *I know, I'll ask it on chat. People are always saying chat is where to go if it's opinion-based and such.* The problem is I have no idea how chat works.

I think I opened a room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34881/star-wars-fan-theories

Am I doing this incorrectly? Nobody has chimed in so far. I just want to hear people's 2-cents on the question **"When has any Star Wars theory turned out to be true?"**

Comment: just go into mos eisley and start chatting. if you really want to, you can invite people into the room from mos eisley. users aren't notified that the room exists, so people probably don't even know about it.

Answer (score 6):

Opening a new room like that is unlikely to get much attention, because no one will know it's there unless they happen to be looking at the site's room list. I can tell you that I, for one, don't do this in a regular basis.

I would recommend that you go into the primary room for the site, [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), and announce the existence of your room to the people there. You may need to do this a few different times, depending on who's active and paying attention.

You could also just ask your question right there in Mos Eisley, especially if the activity has hit a lull, we're always happy for a new topic. (If the chat activity is already high, you might need to wait it out.)

Comment: I think this question specifically was considered not fit for the main site.

Answer (score 5):

You should join an existing room that already has people talking in it.

For this site, [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) is the main chatroom, which means it's usually fine to start there. You can also check [the list of all SF&F chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=scifi.stackexchange.com) in case one of them is obviously more appropriate. At the moment there don't appear to be any active chat rooms focused on Star Wars, so Mos Eisley is probably the best choice.